# Uploadify cancel queue - howto

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify

I was trying to cancel the queue using "$('#file_upload').uploadify('cancel','*');" but for some reason I keep getting an error "Uncaught Call to CancelUpload failed".

When I have a link to clear the queue : works correctly.

But, I have a modal box that contains an uploadify. When you add few files, close the box, followed by entering the modal again : I keep receiving an error "Uncaught Call to CancelUpload failed".

Does some one has a work around it?

This is uploadify 3.

Comment: try $('#file_upload').uploadifyCancel('*'); $('#file_upload').uploadifyClearQueue();

Comment: no, those didn't work. they are not in uploadify 3.2.2. Both commands were joined into .uploadify('cancel','*'); in v3.2.2

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing it using 'destroy' and start uploadify again. *Uploadify should be declared on the element before it can be destroyed.

```
$(function() {
$('#file_upload').uploadify('destroy');
$('#file_upload').uploadify({});
});
```